# In TortoiseGit, which one is MERGE_HEAD and which one is HEAD?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

This is an easy question, but git is really confusing with it's labels, and I couldn't find an answer.

When I have local changes and I want to merge the latest remote repository into my local repository, I do a local commit and then git pull.

When the merge conflicts show up, I have the option to resolve conflict using MERGE_HEAD and to resolve conflict using HEAD

Which one is the remote repository and which one is the local repository?

Thank you

Answer (score 34):

They are *both* local (this is important, albeit not very helpful :-) ).

`HEAD` is your *current branch*, which means *the one you have checked out now*.  For `git merge` that's the one you had checked out when you started.

`MERGE_HEAD` is the *other commit*, which means *the hash ID of the commit you told Git to merge*.  That is, `git merge origin/master` resolves `origin/master` to some local commit hash ID, and then merges that commit, and `MERGE_HEAD` contains the hash ID of that commit.

I think a better term for the other commit is *other* or `--theirs`, and Git sometimes uses those terms, but other bits of Git do use the term *remote* to refer to the `--theirs` commit.

Comment: So, in other words HEAD means the target branch latest commit, and MERGE_HEAD is the source branch latest commit?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves: "Source" and "target" are not good terms either as both inputs are sources. `HEAD` is both the *current commit* **and** the *current branch*. `MERGE_HEAD` is the commit you name in your request to perform the merge, e.g., `git merge bob` to merge the the commit at the tip of branch `bob`; and both commits are sources. There's a third source as well, which is the *merge base* commit, which Git computes for you. Git combines the three sources to produce a new commit, which goes on the *current branch*.

Comment: Note that you run `git checkout alice` to select that branch to start. Alice becomes your current *branch* and her latest commit is now your current *commit* as well. You can now ask Git: *Say: which branch does HEAD name?* and the answer is `alice`, or: *Tell me: which commit does HEAD name?* and the answer is, e.g., `a123456...`. The true name of a commit is its hash ID; `HEAD` can be translated to *either* the branch name *or* the commit hash.

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't answer my "binary" question in simple "yes"/"no" (1/0) termes.

Comment: I've asked this because Tortoise Git has options to "Resolve with HEAD" and "RESOLVE with MERGE_HEAD", and then I had to researsh to find out which commit these labels would be refering to. It happened with binary files, which we can't just look at a "diff" beteween the two versions, and I needed to keep the version of the current branch I was working (the 'checked out branch"), while replacing the version of the same file which were based on the branch I was sending my changes to. This is why I needed to make sure I knew which file version git would keep depending on the option I choosed.

Comment: Well, `HEAD` is the *current commit*, so that would be the "current version" if you think of them that way. The real problem here is that if you're doing rebase, rather than merge, the current commit comes from the *new* branch you're building, and the `--theirs` or MERGE_HEAD commit is from the branch whose commits you're *copying* to make the new ones. So now there's even less of a direct mapping!

Comment: So, HEAD is current, maybe what's local to the place you're concerned with the status of the files at, and MERGE_HEAD is the other, what's remote with respect to the collection of concern.

Comment: The language used in the question may be wrong, but it makes sense to me. The language used in the answer may be correct, but is unclear to me. Therefore, for my purposes: **HEAD = local** and **MERGE_HEAD = remote**.

Comment: TortoiseGit should show HEAD on the left instead of on the right, as other non-conflicted files have the current branch on the left. How to swap HEAD to the left and MERGE_HEAD to the right?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone seeking a quick answer.

```
HEAD = mine , MERGE_HEAD = theirs
```

[image]

For more information, see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-conflicts.html

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this thread while searching for the same issue. I use WinMerge as the merge tool for TortoiseGit, and when resolving a conflict, it displays 3 panes: `MERGE_HEAD` to the left, `Base` in the middle, and `HEAD` to the right.

Turns out that the `MERGE_HEAD` is the commit/branch you are trying to merge, `HEAD` is the commit/branch you are trying to merge to, and `Base` is the merge result that you should edit in order to resolve the conflict.

So, you should edit the code in the middle pane, `Base`, save it, and commit.

*Update 11/11/2021: This answer is inaccurate .. see below comments.*

Comment: This answer is wrong. Winmerge shows Base | Merge_head | Head, and you can only edit head

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Honestly, I still feel confused of the naming every time a conflict takes place :) But it's the pane in the middle that should be edited, right?